# Git commit syntax error results in error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git

One of my commit messages got corrupted somehow, and now git push doesn't work. The error message (shown below) isn't helping me figure out how to fix the problem.

$ git push -f

37:42: syntax error: Expected end of line but found identifier. (-2741)

error: failed to push some refs to [myrepo]

I don't want to overwrite my local version because the code on my local machine is more up-to-date than what is on the repo.  How can I restore my workflow of pushing my most up-to-date code from my machine to the repo?

Comment: That message is not coming from `git push`, nor indeed any part of git itself.  Do you have a pre-push hook, or does the other end have a pre-receive or update hook, that might cause this?  (Lack of `remote:` in front of the error message suggests it's your own pre-push hook.)

Comment: Googling for the error message indicates that it comes from AppleScript. If so, this might be unrelated to git.

Comment: I don't know if I have a pre-push hook.  How do I find out?  How do I interact with AppleScript?